# Delete from database if time is greater than 4 hours

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, sql-delete

I want to delete all records in a database if the timestamp is older than 4 hours.

So my logic is to get the hour of the current time and get the hour of from the timestamp saved in the database and subtract to see if it is greater than 4. If it is greater than 4 than delete the records.

This is a code work in progress not really sure if it is correct.

```
DELETE FROM posts
WHERE id IN 
   (SELECT *
    FROM posts
    WHERE (HOUR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - HOUR(time_published)) > 4)
   )
```

if it makes a difference I am using MySQL.

Comment: When you're debugging `DELETE` logic, always write your `SELECT` statement first so you can see the records which will be deleted.

Comment: Use `SELECT id` not `SELECT *`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not a simple

```
delete 
from posts 
where timestampdiff(hour, current_timestamp, time_published)>=4
```

Note that comparing the hour portions of date fields won't do what you expect. Consider comparing `21st Jan 1985 10:00` and `22nd Jan 1985 11:00`. Your original condition would fail (1 hour), but it's actually 25 hours between them.

Comment: "The future" is relative, all you need is a different day for it to fail.

Comment: hours should be hour, and the division by 3600 looks like a holdover from an earlier query returning the difference in seconds. semantics aside, this is the way to do it.

Comment: You can edit the answer, t-sql is what I use on a daily basis. My mysql is a bit rusty.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm still getting used to SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the record at timestamp 1:00' and run this query at 5:59' nothing will be removed because the time difference is 4:59' and the hour component of that is 4! It might be what you want but that's way closer to 5 hours than 4.
Assuming that minutes are your smallest unit of precision, you might want to do something like

```
DELETE FROM posts
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, time_published) > 240
```

And use nested queries only when they are absolutely necessary; they possibly could slow your operations down drastically.